# Problema sesiones y vistas en index con PHP

Tags: php, html, aplicación-web

Buenas tardes comunidad de programadores,
Estoy haciendo un login con vistas mediante un index.php mediante MVC y me surgen 2 inconvenientes.
El primero es el tema de las vistas, quiero que al clickear en el menú lateral de mi dashboard.php cargue otra vista pero no se como detectar ese click en un componente que no es un botón en el index.php. Muestro código de ejemplo del index y del botón del dashboard.

Index.php

```php
<?php
include_once 'includes/user.php';
include_once 'includes/user_session.php';

$errorLogin = "";

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    # Existe sesion
    # Inicio sesion_start() con el constructor de $userSession
    $user->setUser($userSession->getCurrentUser());

    # Obtiene información del perfil para el dashboard
    require_once("model/profile_model.php");

    $profile = new profile_model();
    $profiledata = $profile->getProfile();

    include_once 'dashboard.php';

}else if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    # No existe sesion #
    $userForm = $_POST['username'];
    $passForm = $_POST['password'];
    
    $userSession = new UserSession();
    $user = new User();
    if($user->userExists($userForm, $passForm)){
        # Los datos coinciden y se inicia sesion #
        $userSession->setCurrentUser($userForm);
        $user->setUser($userForm);
        # Dashboard Controllers #
        require_once("model/profile_model.php");

        $profile = new profile_model();
        $profiledata = $profile->getProfile();

        foreach ($profiledata as $variable){
            echo "<a>" . $variable . "</a>";
        }
        include_once 'dashboard.php';
        # Los datos no coinciden y rechaza la conexion #
    }else{ 
        $errorLogin = "Credenciales inválidas";
        include_once 'login.php';
    }
}else{
    # No existe sesion y creamos una #
    $userSession = new UserSession();
    $user = new User();
    include_once 'login.php';
}
?>
```

Botón dashboard.php

```html
    <li><a class="ai-icon mm-active" href="dashboard.php" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="flaticon-025-dashboard"></i>
              <span class="nav-text">Panel de control</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Cuando clickeo en el botón me redirecciona a dashboard.php por el HREF, pero lo que quiero es gestionar todo mediante el index.php y no acceder al dashboard directamente así gestiono la sesión mediante el index y no manualmente en cada vista.

El segundo problema es que cuando inicio sesión e ingreso al dashboard, al momento de escribir mi URL por ejemplo localhost/index.php y presionar enter mi sesión se destruye y me envía nuevamente al login.

Comment: Puedes usar la escucha de eventos de Javascript para escuchar los clicks de los elementos. ¿Has investigado algo sobre eso? ¿Has intentando algo al respecto? En cuanto a la segunda parte de la pregunta, no se entiende cuál es el problema.

Comment: Claro, setOnClickListener() pero como envio esa información al index.php para hacer el sistema de vistas? He intentado muchas cosas al respecto, sino no haria este post. Con respecto a la segunda pregunta, por que se destruye la sesion al realizar lo descrito previamente, ese es el segundo inconveniente

Comment: Te recomiendo que abordes un problema por pregunta y que expliques bien el contexto. Si quieres escuchar los clicks en un elemento, agrega el código Javascript que usas para ello y explícanos con claridad el contexto y qué es lo que no funciona exactamente. ¿Quieres pasar datos de un archivo a otro? ¿o quieres modificar la vista en el mismo archivo donde ocurre el click? Si es lo primero, deberás usar Ajax, si es lo segundo, deberás explicarnos más cosas del contexto. Tu pregunta ahora mismo es todavía confusa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien, lo que quieres es usar `index.php` para procesar todo. Es una buena estrategia para tener control de la aplicación general, así todas las consultas pasan por ese archivo que se encarga de administrar (los CMS que conozco usan esa estrategia).

para lograr eso tienes que parametrizar tu página.
por ejemplo, en el link, en vez de `dashboard.php` usar el mismo `index.php?view=dashboard` y en tu `index.php` procesar el parámetro, por ejemplo:

```
if($_GET['view'] == 'dashboard'){
    include 'dashboard.php'
}
```

o algo más genérico con los views en una carpeta:

```
$views_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/views/';
if(file_exists($views_path . $_GET['view'])){
    include $views_path . $_GET['view'];
}
```

Extendiendo un poco esa forma de hacer, puedes parametrizar el controlador y la vista, por ejemplo `index.php?controller=usuarios&view=lista` y desde php ir manejando **qué archivos se incluyen y qué consultas se realizan según esos parámetros.** Así tu `index.php` tomará inteligentemente cada consulta (y no tendrás que hacer un `.php` para cada cosa). Obviamente habrá que revisar la forma en que no implique fallas de seguridad.

Esta idea se puede extrapolar tambien para el uso de plantillas, por ejemplo: incluyes un `header.php` que es genérico, en el body haces todo el manejo de contenido que varía, e incluyes un `footer.php` que también es genérico.

El paso siguiente sería realizar la rescritura de url para que en vez de `mipagina.com/index.php?controller=usuarios&view=lista` puedas usar algo como `mipagina.com/usuarios/lista`. Esa reescritura es desde el servidor (se configura en `.htaccess` para apache, o en el archivo respectivo de `nginx`

Respecto a tu otra consulta sobre las sesiones, debes revisar que para utilizar el contenido de `$_SESSION`, debes llamar `session_start()` antes.

Según tu código, estás tratando de verificar `$_SESSION['username']` antes de sentenciar `session_start()`.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    # Existe sesion
    # Inicio sesion_start() con el constructor de $userSession
    $user->setUser($userSession->getCurrentUser());
...
```

y para que funcione como deseas debería ser algo como

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){...
```

o de esta forma si es que adivino más o menos como tienes hecho el constructor:

```
$user->setUser($userSession->getCurrentUser());
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){...
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos.